# Plotting graph in perl

Tags: perl, graph

[image: first graph]graph 1
[image: graph2]I am very new to perl and plotting graph is something which i am learning. Here is a code.

```
@user_list = (sort { $user_list{$a} <=> $user_list{$b} } keys %user_list);
@data = \@user_list;

# Goes through the weeks and add each week info to the data array
my $size = scalar @weeks;
    if ($size > 4)
{
    $start = $size - 4;
    print $start;
}
for my $i ($start..($size - 1))
{
    my @week = @{$weeks[$size - $i - 1]};
    foreach my $x (@week) { $x = ceil($x / 7); }
    @data = (@data, \@week);
    }

$graph = GD::Graph::bars->new(1200,600);

$graph->set( 
    x_label => 'Weeks',
    y_label => 'Average Total Open Cases Per User',
    title => 'Alpha Cases Weekly Trend Per User',
    transparent => 0,
    bargroup_spacing => 3,
    show_values => 1
);
    $graph->set_legend(@week_start_dates);
$gd = $graph->plot(\@data);
open(IMG, '> /var/www/cgi-bin/remedy-case-management/graphs/Alpha_Cases.png') or die $!;
binmode IMG;
print IMG $gd->gif;
close IMG;
```

I am troubleshooting a graph which shows first 4 weeks in x-axis.i.e 
  @week_start_dates=Jul-26-2014 Aug-02-2014 Aug-09-2014 Aug-16-2014 Aug-23-2014 Aug-30-2014 Sep-06-2014 Sep-13-2014

So when I print the graph it shows the first 4 weeks from Jul 26 to Aug-16 as in the first graph in picture but I wanted to print Aug23-Sep13.

So if I do not reverse the @week_start_dates it shows  as in the second graph:
Sep-13-2014 Sep-6-2014 Aug-30-2014 Aug 23-2014

I do not know where exactly in the code it is trimming to display only 4 weeks.I want to print this in x-axis.
Aug-23-104 Aug-30-2014 Sep-6-2014 Sep-13-2014

Should I use @week_start_dates=substr function to display the last 4 weeks dates.?It's actually trimming only 4 weeks somewhere in the code and I am not able to find out that.Can help is much appreciated?

Comment: jm666-I didn't paste the entire code but this part of code is plotting the graphs.Just the data part.

Comment: sorry for pasting wrong code before, I didn't realize.Added the correct code now.

Comment: Does this makes sense?

Comment: jm666-Ignore the above data.I have just one simple question. I have a array @week_start_dates=Jul-28-2014 Aug-04-2014 Aug-11-2014 Aug-18-2014 Aug-25-2014 Sep-01-2014 Sep-08-2014 Sep-15-2014
 . When I plot it I need to print in this order. Aug-25-2014 Sep-01-2014 Sep-08-2014 Sep-15-2014.So it actually prints only 4 weeks (the first 4 weeks).i want to print the last weeks starting from aug 25 to sep 15. Do you know how to print it reverse when plotting.

Comment: if I reverse the array @ week_start_dates=reverse(@week_start_dates).It prints from Sep 15 Sep 8 Aug 25 Aug 18 but it should be Aug 18-Sep15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the question from your comment:

> I have a array

```
@week_start_dates = Jul-28-2014 Aug-04-2014 Aug-11-2014 Aug-18-2014 Aug-25-2014 Sep-01-2014 Sep-08-2014 Sep-15-2014 .
```

> When I
>   plot it I need to print in this order.

```
Aug-25-2014 Sep-01-2014 Sep-08-2014 Sep-15-2014.
```

> So it actually prints only 4 weeks (the first 4 weeks).i want to print the last weeks starting from aug 25 to sep 15.

Learn about the array slices, here [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices). Demo of getting some parts of arrays.

```
use feature 'say';
use strict;
use warnings;

my(@wsd) = qw(Jul-28-2014 Aug-04-2014 Aug-11-2014 Aug-18-2014 Aug-25-2014 Sep-01-2014 Sep-08-2014 Sep-15-2014);

say "@wsd"; #the whole array
#Jul-28-2014 Aug-04-2014 Aug-11-2014 Aug-18-2014 Aug-25-2014 Sep-01-2014 Sep-08-2014 Sep-15-2014

say "@wsd[2..5]"; # from 2 up to 5 (indexed from 0)
#Aug-11-2014 Aug-18-2014 Aug-25-2014 Sep-01-2014

say "@wsd[0,-1]"; #0 and last
#Jul-28-2014 Sep-15-2014

say "@wsd[-4..-1]"; #last 4
#Aug-25-2014 Sep-01-2014 Sep-08-2014 Sep-15-2014
```

and so on...

Comment: Thanks you so much jm666. Thanks for your patience and answers.

Comment: @javalearner ok, glad to have help, deleting unnecessary comments from the above...